# No se reproduce mi audio con AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift

Intento reproducir el audio de un enlace cuando presiono un botón determinado, pero nada se escucha. Este es mi código:

```
@IBAction func Reproducir(sender: AnyObject) {

    let urlString = "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/marchas/\(pasarid).mp3"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url!)

    avPlayer.play()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVPlayer` solo funciona si lo declaras como una variable global. Por ejemplo:

```
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer?

    @IBAction func Reproducir(sender: AnyObject) {

        let urlString = "http://elpenitente.playcofrade.com/marchas/\(pasarid).mp3"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url!)
        avPlayer?.play()
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya funciona. Disculpa pero soy nuevo en esto y tengo una duda que no he conseguido programar. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que cuando se empiece a reproducir el botón cambie el texto a pausa y cuando se pulse pause la reproducción? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Para el tema del botón, haz otra pregunta ya que son cosas distintas.